# Generating randomized pairs of elements in php

Tags: php, arrays, random

I want to generate random pairs of elements and have this code:

```
<? 
$myarray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myarray2=array('1a','2a','3a'); 

echo '<p>'.$myarray1[array_rand($myarray1)].'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$myarray2[array_rand($myarray2)].'</p>'; 
?>
```

but I get this as a result:

```
<p>3</p>
<p>2a</p>

or

<p>1</p>
<p>3a</p>

or

<p>2</p>
<p>1a</p>

etc.
```

and I want to only get certain pairs:

```
<p>2</p>
<p>2a</p>

or

<p>1</p>
<p>1a</p>

or

<p>3</p>
<p>3a</p>

etc.
```

how do I achieve that?

Comment: Well `array_rand()` returns a random key and if both arrays have the same keys and same amount of elements you can just use the random key returned from `array_rand()` for both arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only call `array_rand` once only.

```
<? 
$myarray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myarray2=array('1a','2a','3a'); 

$rand = array_rand($myarray1); // assuming $myarray1 has the exactly same keys as $myarray2
echo '<p>'.$myarray1[$rand].'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$myarray2[$rand].'</p>'; 
?>
```

If they have different keys, you can try using [`array_values`](http://php.net/array-values):

```
$myarray1 = ["a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c" => "3"];
$myarray2 = ["d" => "1a", "e" => "2b", "f" => "3c"];

$myarray1 = array_values($myarray1);
$myarray2 = array_values($myarray2);
$rand = array_rand($myarray1);
echo '<p>'.$myarray1[$rand].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$myarray2[$rand].'</p>';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$myarray1=array('1','2','3'); 
$myarray2=array('1a','2a','3a'); 

$key_rand = array_rand($myarray1);

echo '<p>'.$myarray1[$key_rand].'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$myarray2[$key_rand].'</p>';
```

use same key for both

Answer (score 1):

You are calling array_rand twice which is why you are getting random pairs. Assuming the two arrays are the same length (or have the same keys for an associative array) you could do something like this:

```
$key = array_rand($myarray1);
echo '<p>'.$myarray1[$key].'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$myarray2[$key].'</p>';
```